# How to refresh chat message div based on message id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

Currently I am using ajax to refresh the messages div every second, however the messages div will not show after refresh or after reply a message. The page url is like http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~mp261/Pepero%20College/tutor_message.php?id=1

This is my javascript:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('#messages')
        .load('tutor_message.php?_=' + Math.random() + ' #messages')
        .fadeIn("slow")
    ;
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

How should I add in the id to the script above? Is it possible to do so?
Sorry if my question is not clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    // ajax call to load messages
    var url = 'tutor_message.php?_=' + Math.random();
    $.ajax({
      url: url, 
      success: function(data)
      {
         // do something with response data
         // assuming data is a page with messages in element with id=messages
         var newMessages = $(data).find("#messages").html(); // get message data from request somehow
         $('#messages').html(newMessages); // show new messages on page
      }
    });
}, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```